# "Invalid object dbo.RoleUsers" error using EF Database-first on insert

Tags: sql-server, database, entity-framework, associations, ef-database-first

I have a DB from which I have generated the models using Database-First through Entity Framework.

The picture below shows what's in the database:

[image: User-UserRoles-Roles: many-to-many relation]

When I do the following in my code (inserting a user with the associated role):

```
        using (var context = new ApplicationDbContext())
        {
            var role = new Role {Name = "Admin"};  
            var user = new User {UserName = username,
                                 PasswordHash = passwordHash,
                                 Roles = new List<Role> { role }};
            
            context.Set<User>().Add(user);
            context.SaveChanges(); //Error here
        }
```

It throws the following error:

```
An error occurred while saving entities that do not expose foreign key properties for their relationships. The EntityEntries property will return null because a single entity cannot be identified as the source of the exception. Handling of exceptions while saving can be made easier by exposing foreign key properties in your entity types. See the InnerException for details.
```

and in the **InnerException** I get:

```
Invalid object name dbo.RoleUsers
```

which is pretty strange since I have a table **UserRoles**, not **RoleUsers**.

Does anyone knows what the source of the error is here?

Thanks,
Ionut

Comment: Something to do with EF Not being able to figure out the name of the joiner table

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42425830/code-migration-unexpectedly-tries-to-rename-table