# Generate missing migrations so I can update an old database structure

Tags: entity-framework-migrations

I am using EF Code first with Migrations.  I need to update an old database
however I have lost some of the migration code.
Is there a way to generate the missing migrations?

Comment: looking in to using the Entity Data Model Wizard to create the code first model for the old database.

Comment: Have you tried  update-database -script from the package manager command line. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj591621(v=vs.113).aspx

Comment: no point if I don't have the right migrations to run.

Comment: *First step before running the wizard is to remove the old __MigrationHistory table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step 1: Back up ( obviously )

Step 2: Delete __MigrationHistory

Step 3: Create a temporary project. 
        Use the Entity Data Model Wizard to create the Code-First Model.

Step 4: Enable migrations in the new project  ( using Enable-Migrations) at the Package Manager Console.
        Create an initial migration ( using add-migration one). Comment out the Up and Down methods of the created migration.
        Run update-database.

Step 5:  Replace all the files in the Migrations folder of the original project with the files in the temporary project.  Editing DbContext and namespace names as required.

Step 6  In the original project in package manager run Add-Migration two 
        then run update-database

Comment: I had to make a lot of alterations to the "two" migration.  I will be more careful not to loose old migrations in future.